# I want my post to add when i press the load more button without plugin can anyone help me

Tags: wordpress

I have created pagination for my `Wordpress` post. Now I want it in a single page. When I click the load more button, remaining posts should load on the same page.

How to do it without plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wordpress' built in functions to achieve this.
How to do this is explained here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Example_Loop_with_Pagination